# Computer management snap in: how to connect to a remote computer running windows 2016 server core?

Tags: windows, windows-server, windows-server-2016

I just rent a windows 2016 server core that is located in a datacenter. I want to manage this server from my home computer. I can easily connect to it via remote desktop, however I need to access the computer management snap in (that as far as i know their is no way to access it via the remote desktop or command line or powershell) :

[image]

So i try to click on "connect to another computer ...", enter the IP address of the server and i receive this error message

[image]

And here i m :( I even try to disconnect the firewall on the server (`Set-NetFirewallProfile -Profile Domain,Public,Private -Enabled false`) but it's didn't help :(

So what is the exact procedure to follow to connect the computer management snap in to another computer ?
I need to access from the computer management snapin the "device manager" and the "disk management"

NOTE:

I m able to connect using server manager

[image]

(for this i added the ip of the server in the trusthost) but as soon as i try to access the computer management (even from server manager) i have the previous error :(

thanks you by advance

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough points to comment.

What's the version of Windows at Home?. It works only on Windows 10 professional/Enterprise or Windows Server and you need to install RSAT tool.Download from Microsoft website.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=45520

Check this video on youtube ,How to enable RSAT after installation.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eBdEoczETDY

Comment: Thanks @sam, i try to connect from from from windows 8.1 or from a windows server 2016 GUI (running in virtual box), none of them work with  computer management :( it's work for the remote desktop or for the server manager but not for computer management andI can't understand why :(

Comment: What version of Windows 8.1(Home or Professional?) ?Did you enable and set up remote management access on data center server? and WinRM listener is up and running on data center server?.

Comment: windows 8.1 professional. Not sure what to do to enable and set up remote management access of the server core. I did it via sconfig (Enable remote management). winrm e winrm/config/listener return me the http listener. I also deactivate the firewal didn't help