# How to manage the device (update drivers, see with device are faulty, etc.) of a windows server 2016 core?

Tags: windows, windows-server

I just installed windows server 2016 core. Now how can I manage the device drivers (or see with device are in fault) as their is no devmgmt.msc on server core ?

Answer (score 0):

Run `mmc` on your management machine, click file -> Add Snap-In or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd> and select the device management MMC. If you add it you can tell it to work on a remote machine (your core server).

Alternatively you might be able to use WMI or PowerShell but I'm not sure about the commands in that case.

Comment: thanks @Seth, but i tried this, and no way to make it working, it's always gave me error and unable to connect ( https://superuser.com/questions/1334911/computer-management-snap-in-how-to-connect-to-a-remote-computer-running-windows )

Comment: If you entered the IP it's kind of strange that he would report the name "2012R2Core". Are you sure you used the correct IP? It does look like you actually used a name to connect.

Comment: the copy is just a screenshot that i found on the web that is exactly same as mine (sorry I did it fastly). But i confirm you that it's report the IP of the server ... I can't understand why it's not work. Note that it's a non domain server

Comment: If it's not working it's likely that some kind of network filter (firewall, threat management gateway or similar) is interfering. Alternatively you could install the "Desktop Experience" Feature. This would pretty much make it a standard edition server though.

Comment: i deactivate the firewall so i don't think it's could be this. after it's a fresh install of windows, so i don't know what else it's could be :( i can gave you the credential of the server and you will see everything is clean on this server